# Parse Backbone.js Handlebars [Object object]

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

Rather new to handlbars.js but my #each is functional until I try to access a nested attribute. Specifically author.name

```
<!-- Handlebars.js Blog Template -->
<script id="posts-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each post}}
<div class="blog-post">
    <h2 class="blog-post-title"><a href="#">{{title}}</a></h2>
      <p class="blog-post-meta">{{author.name}}</p>
    <div>{{{body}}}</div>
</div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Chrome Javascript console shows author as having attribute 'name' with the correct data.

The Backbone.js view appears to be working also:

```
var PostsView =  Parse.View.extend({
template: Handlebars.compile($('#posts-tpl').html()),
render: function(){ 
    var collection = { post: this.collection.toJSON() };
    this.$el.html(this.template(collection));
}
```

I have a full example at http://picze.co/blog

Comment: Sorry but what is the question?

Comment: Apologize for that. The author.name property wasn't rendering - tuns out I wasn't getting back the data I thought I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at what you're passing into the template, you'll see the issue.

In your `render` function, try inspecting what `this.collection.toJSON();` actually is.

Basically, it looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        author: {
            __type: "pointer",
            className: "_User",
            objectId: "JCAjG1AIN0"
        },
        title: "WTFBBQ",
        body: "<p><h3>test</h3> egg on face. This cannot be good. </p>"   
    }
]
```

Looks like the `author` is missing the `name` attribute

### EDIT

Seems like the `name` attribute exists in the model but it's nested as another model so when you call `.toJSON()` you won't get it.

One way would be to include the `author` model as well:

```
var collection = { post: this.collection.toJSON() };
for (var i=0; i<collection.post.length; i++) {
    if (collection.post[i].author) {
        collection.post[i].author = this.collection.at(i).get('author').toJSON();
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar with parse.js so this may not be the best solution, but it should work

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to look into my Parse query that has author as a pointer to the User "table"

Comment: Still stuck, I see this.collection looks as you stated but when the page is rendered in Chrome the JavaScript Console is letting me expand "author" and see the attributes I'm looking for :/ I'm missing something 'easy' that I just don't fully understand.

Comment: You nailed it. Fully functional. It was pulling it out of the collection at the specified index to then execute the .get() that I was missing. Appreciate it!